# SendMessage and PostMessage which one is better to use?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, mfc, message-queue, sendmessage

searching the web for the difference between these two function calls, I've found that:

*The difference between these two API calls is the way that they return control to the calling application. With **SendMessage** control is not returned to the calling application until the window that the message was sent to has completed processing the sent message, however with **PostMessage** control is returned to the calling application immediately, regardless of weather or not the sent message has been processes.*

***postMessage:** Sends a message in the message queue associated with the thread and returns without waiting for the thread to process that messaage.*

***SendMessage:** calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.*

***PostMessage** is a Asynchronous function where as **SendMessage** is a synchronous function.*

Now the question is for my application ( which needs high performance ) which function is better to be used?

Note that I'm using MFC in visual studio 2010 and for this code:

```
CWnd *pParentOfClass = CWnd::GetParent();
pParentOfClass ->
```

I just have these functions for sending messsages:

- PostMessageW
- SendMessage
- SendMessageW

**More questions:**
Can you tell me the difference between **SendMessage** and **SendMessageW**?

Comment: It depends on what message(s) you want to send -- could you give some examples?

Comment: well it needs more explanation. I'll soon edit my question. please see the edited section. thanks @EdwardClements

Comment: Please dont ask two questions in the same post.

Comment: I upvoted this questions because it has all the info I wanted about these two apis

Answer (score 23):

You actually already answered your own question by describing SendMessage and PostMessage.

**SendMessage:** Sends a message and waits until the procedure which is responsible for the message finishes and returns.

**PostMessage:** Sends a message to the message queue and returns immediately. But you don't know when that message is actually being processed. Therefore, if you should be expecting an answer from that processed message, you will most likely get it through a message as well.

It really depends which one to use, but the end results are pretty much the same, it's just about timing. Also, PostMessage is especially useful in multi-threaded applications, which allows you to safely communicate between threads via their created windows.

PostMessage or SendMessage that end with A or W are just indicators how strings will be interpreted, i.e. single or multibyte, respectively. The ones without the A or W ending are preprocessor macros and will delegate to whatever you're application is set up to.

Comment: can you explain this part more? **The ones without the A or W ending are preprocessor macros and will delegate to whatever you're application is set up to.**

Comment: Shouldn't be too important, just use the generic ones (i.e. without special endings). See [ANSI/Unicode in WinAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Infact @no_seriously, I understood from your answer that if I expect the handler to return a value and do my process based on that value, I should use SendMessage but the main question is which one has better performance. A part of your answer says **it's just about timing** Could you explain it a little more?

Comment: Well, taking it very strictly, I'd say SendMessage is "faster" since it doesn't have to go through the message queue and gets processed right away. PostMessage delays the processing until the messages, which were in the queue before the message was posted, were processed. So to make it simple and satisfying, **SendMessage is faster**. But once again, that shouldn't be the main concern when talking about high performance, it all depends on what exactly you want to archive.

Comment: @sepideh If you are asking about a performance comparison between two API calls that do different things, you are doing it wrong.